# Load Dynamic css files in component on the basis of routes?

Tags: angular

There are 3 CSS files in my component and I want to load them on the basis of some condition. if condition1 satisfied load CSS1 and so on. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

What you could do, however, is load all CSS files and use a `[class.XXX]` attribute on your highest container. You declare 3 main classes in your CSS and with this statement, only apply one.